# C++ Constructor inheritance not working correctly

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, linker-errors

This is the dependent class header

```
#ifndef TransHeader
#define TransHeader
#include <string>
#include "CipherHeader.h"

using namespace std;
class Trans : public Cipher {
    public:
    Trans(string filenameIn);
    const static int MAXSIZE = 10000;
    void createArray();
    void transEncrypt();
    void transDecrypt();


    private:
        //string Key;
        //string inputData;
        char dataArray[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];


};

#endif
```

This is the inherited header

```
#ifndef CipherHeader
#define CipherHeader
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Cipher {
    public:
        const static int MAXSIZE = 10000;
        Cipher(string filenameIn);
        void getKey();
        void flagHandle(string);
        string Key;
        string inputData;
        string filename;
        string flags;

        string readFile();
        void writeFile();
    private:




};

#endif
```

The problem is after I call the base constructor

```
Trans::Trans(string filenameIn) : Cipher(filenameIn) {}
```

I cannot call the constructor in a normal file like so:

```
#include "Trans.cpp"

int main() {
string a  = "asdf";
Trans *c = new Trans(a);

}
```

This results in this error:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.out
/tmp/ccbuqMYr.o: In function `Trans::Trans(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `Cipher::Cipher(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/tmp/ccbuqMYr.o: In function `Trans::Trans(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `Cipher::Cipher(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

replacing Trans with Cipher works just fine and runs.  I have tried everything I know, googled excessively, and cannot figure out this error.  Other design problems, ect will be dealt with later, this is my main problem.  Please help.

EDIT:: definition of Cipher

```
Cipher::Cipher(string filenameIn) {

filename = filenameIn;

readFile();
getKey();

}
```

Comment: This is a linker error. You have either missed the definition of `Cipher::Cipher()` or the `.cpp` file where this definition resides.

Comment: Very late response, but if I remember correctly, this guy solved my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all the source files in the build:

```
g++ test.cpp trans.cpp cipher.cpp -o test
```

This will give you a new error because you're including the `trans.cpp` source file from `test.cpp`, rather than the header file - fix that, and it should build with no further problems.

Comment: That worked, now I'm just dealing with a segmentation fault, which is a different problem I suspect!  Thank you!

Comment: Well replacing Trans with Cipher in the test file runs without segmentation fault... If you have any idea why, I would appreciate it

Comment: Fixed that, your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Ok rule 1 - never ever ever put a 'using' statement in a header file! ;-)

Ok you need to call the base class constructor.

So :

```
Trans::Trans(const std::string &f) // notice pass by reference
    :Cipher(f)
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to fix this.  I tried retrieving the string from the user using cin, but that didn't work.

Comment: <sigh> try #include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
   public:
      Base(const std::string &f)
         :m_name(f)
      {
      }
   private:
      std::string m_name;
};

class Deriv: public Base
{
   public:
      Deriv(const std::string &f)
         :Base(f)
      {
      }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Deriv f("foobar");

   return 0;
}

Comment: That reduced the error to this:
/tmp/cckdWTT6.o: In function `Trans::Trans(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5TransC1ERKSs[Trans::Trans(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Cipher::Cipher(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'